# Json parsing of data and getting the value by providing the key

Tags: c, json

I have a character string in json format.I am using jansson library.

```
{"ip": null, "hostname": null, "updated_at": 1507729189,"device_category": "Unknown", "device_name": "Unknown", "device_family": "Unknown", "mac": "005056bd7f9c", "added_at": 1507729189}
```

I need to get the values corresponding to the key.

```
json_t *data = NULL;
if(!(data = json_object_get((json_t *)&recvBuff->data, "mac")))
{
    status = ERROR;
    goto exit;
}
strcpy(client_data->clientMac, json_string_value(data));
```

In the above code i tried to get the mac address value.But here i am facing the issue as json_object_get accepts a json object . But recvBuff->data is uint8_t type and its values is the string which i had provided.so i tried type casting but it did not work.
Is there anyway i can convert the string to json object and use json_object_get?

Comment: Take a look at json_loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to tell jansson to parse the JSON string into a hierarchical structure for further use:

```
json_error_t error;
json_p = json_load_file(recvBuff->data, JSON_DISABLE_EOF_CHECK, &error);
if (json_p == NULL)
{
  LOG_PRINT(LOGLEVEL_ERROR, "Loading json string failed: %s - %s; pos=%u\n",
                             error.text, error.source, error.position);
  status = ERROR;
  goto _exit;
}
```

Then you can try to find your key/value pairs. This can be done in 2 flavours:

1)

```
int result;
char *mac_value_p = NULL;
result = json_unpack(json_p, "{s:s}", "mac", &mac_value_p);
if (result)
{
  status = ERROR;
  goto _exit;
}
// mac_value_p now points to a string holding the value.
strcpy(client_data->clientMac, mac_value_p);
```

For other value types than "string" you need to adjust the format string `"{s:s}"`.
With this method you can also query multiple values for different keys at once.

2)

```
json_t *mac_p = NULL;
mac_p = json_object_get(json_p, "mac");
if (!mac_p || !json_is_string(mac_p))
{
  status = ERROR;
  goto exit;
}
// mac_p now points to a json_t object of type string.
strcpy(client_data->clientMac, json_string_value(mac_p));
```